# File write happening asynchronously?

Tags: java, ruby, filesystems

In my Ruby on Rails app I'm having a routine that writes to a file (through a java application) and then reads the written file.

```
write_to_file(file.path, data)
read_file(file.path)
```

Most of the time this works just fine. But some times it looks like the file write had not happened but there were no errors either. And when I retry the routine with the same data it has worked each time.

I have begun to think if the file write happens asynchronously and the file is actually read before the data is written to the disk. Would this be possible?

`write_to_file` calls a java application through a socket connection that takes care of the writing. Java application returns a simple json string back to Rails.

Answer (score 3):

This question is really "what does the Java code do?" and is not really a Ruby question.  It's not even really a Java question, because the Java language allows (of course) any kind of implementation.

The Java code could certainly be returning before the file is available for reading.  We have no idea.  It could be posting a request to a queue, and then returning, for example.

The Java code is what you need to look at. If you don't want to bother with that, you could always do something like this:

```
sleep 0.01 until File.readable?(file.path)
```

This is a bit crude and there are more elegant ways to do this, but it would work.

Comment: I just added to the answer a workaround using `sleep`.

Comment: Thank you. Is the `File.readable?` enough? I mean, my process has been able to read the file, but the content has not been updated. The java app is modifying an existing file, not creating a new one. Should I look at the file timestamp to determine if the file really has been updated?

Comment: Hmm.. The file timestamp includes only seconds. All this can happen in one second. And in the java app it uses Apache POI's functions to update an excel file. So it really boils down how POI saves the file.

Comment: You're right, in that case, File.readable? would not be enough.  Yes, I guess the `until` condition could be when the file's modification date/time is later than the date/time you call the write method. This might be tricky though -- what if on the Java side they flush the file but have more to write?  Why don't you have the Java side send you the content over the socket?

Comment: Can you use JRuby?  Then you don't even need sockets, you just make method calls into Java.  Much simpler.

Comment: I used JRuby earlier. Hated it all the time. Mainly because of the slowness during the development, and also because of the "Out of Memory" errors when it was supposed to print an exception report. And it didn't help giving it several GB memory. It still consumed it all if there was an exception when it was handling a big file for example.

Comment: Yes, JRuby takes a couple of seconds to startup, but the rest of it doesn't sound right -- that is, I'm sure you experienced it but there may have been a way to fix it.  In the future if you reconsider, you have as a resource (in addition to SO) the JRuby Users mailing list (https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/MailingLists). We can discuss this further in a chat if you like.

Comment: @Mika Your input over at https://github.com/jruby/jruby/issues/216 would be extremely valuable. My mention of you revived some interest in the issue, and some key JRuby and Rails people want to look into it further but need more data points, esp. which Rails version it was.

Answer (score 0):

You might be experiencing file buffering where small amounts of data aren't written to the file unless it's flushed. I'm not sure what interface you're using here, but the [`flush`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/IO.html#method-i-flush) method is intended to deal with this exact situation.